# What's going on in this do while loop with break?

Tags: javascript, loops, break

I'm trying to understand how this do/while loop with a `break` statement works. I thought that whenever the break statement is executed (the first two iterations, since the if condition is true those times but not the third time), the for loop is escaped and therefore n isn't incremented. But the line `` console.log(`n is ${n}`) `` logs `n is 2` `n is 2` `n is 5` -- how does it jump from 2 to 5? I thought it would be 3 the third time (when the if condition isn't true, since `quot` is `60` and `60 % 2` does equal 0, and therefore the `break` statement isn't executed).

```
  // newArray = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

  var quot = 0;
  var loop = 1;
  var n;

  do {
        quot = newArr[0] * loop * newArr[1];
        for (n = 2; n < newArr.length; n++) {
          if (quot % newArr[n] !== 0) {
            break;
          }
        }

        console.log(`n is ${n}`)

        loop++;
   } while (n !== newArr.length);
```

Here's the full code (a solution for a freeCodeCamp [challenge](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple/)):

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // Sort array from greater to lowest
  // This line of code was from Adam Doyle (http://github.com/Adoyle2014)
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });

  // Create new array and add all values from greater to smaller from the
  // original array.
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = arr[0]; i >= arr[1]; i--) {
    newArr.push(i);
  }

  // Variables needed declared outside the loops.
  var quot = 0;
  var loop = 1;
  var n;

  // Run code while n is not the same as the array length.
  do {
    quot = newArr[0] * loop * newArr[1];
    for (n = 2; n < newArr.length; n++) {
      if (quot % newArr[n] !== 0) {
        break;
      }
    }

    console.log(`n is ${n}`)

    loop++;
  } while (n !== newArr.length);

  return quot;
}

// test here
smallestCommons([1,5]);
```

Comment: You do not have a log statement inside the `for` loop, so the `for` loop may increment `n` from 2 to 5 (or more) without any intermediate number being logged

Comment: To put backticks in code blocks, use double-backticks as the code block delimiter, rather than single backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array length is 5, so if your if statement and break are not executed, then n will always be 5.

(n = 2; n < newArr.length; n++)

The last time this is executed, `n=4, n < newArr.length (which is 5), n++ (now n is 5)`

Like you said in your question "the if condition isn't true, since quot is 60 and 60 % 2 does equal 0, and therefore the break statement isn't executed"

Your break statement will only serve to get you out of your for loop early, if your for loop completes it's full cycle then n will always be 5.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks, this helped. It was still confusing to me, then finally I got that the reason for the jump is that since on the third iteration if is false, the interpreter stays inside the for loop till it's done, and only then is the console log of n reached.